# ng-repeat / ng-bind wont show my data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-bind

The problem that i am getting is that my ng-repeat / ng-bind won't show the data inside $scope.articles. while in the console i get the data im expecting.
I now made a code snippit so it's easier to discover the problem.

```js
var App = angular.module('App', []);
App.controller('WebCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.start = [{
    "id": 1,
    "text": "test1"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "text": "test2"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "text": "test3"
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "text": "test4"
  }];
  $scope.articles = $scope.start;

  $http.get('/')
    .then(function() {
      $scope.menu = function(id) {
        $scope.articles = $scope.start[id];
        console.log($scope.articles);
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="App">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Todos $http</title>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="WebCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li style="list-style: none">
      <button ng-click="menu(0)">1</button>
      <button ng-click="menu(1)">2</button>
      <button ng-click="menu(2)">3</button>
      <button ng-click="menu(3)">4</button>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li style="list-style: none" ng-repeat="article in articles">
      {{article.text}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The problem might be that the `$scope.menu` function is being called before the request is done since this is AJAX. Do you get an error in your console? Could you provide a complete fiddle?

Comment: write your code on jsfiddle.com instead on pastenbin

Comment: I edited the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code starts with an articles object pointing to an array. Inside menu, it gets replaced by an object. ng-repeat iterates over its keys.

I guess the main change would be:

```
$scope.articles = $scope.start.slice(id, id + 1);
```

```js
var App = angular.module('App', []);
App.controller('WebCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.start = [{
    "id": 1,
    "text": "test1"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "text": "test2"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "text": "test3"
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "text": "test4"
  }];
  $scope.articles = $scope.start;

      $scope.menu = function(id) {
        $scope.articles = $scope.start.slice(id, id + 1);
        console.log($scope.articles);
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="App">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Todos $http</title>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="WebCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li style="list-style: none">
      <button ng-click="menu(0)">1</button>
      <button ng-click="menu(1)">2</button>
      <button ng-click="menu(2)">3</button>
      <button ng-click="menu(3)">4</button>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li style="list-style: none" ng-repeat="article in articles">
      {{article.text}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```